# How can I dismiss MFMessageComposeViewController to mainView Controller?

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller, dismiss

Lets say I have two controller A & B and 1 MFMessageComposeViewController. 
I am performing these operations

A-> presentModalViewController -> B

B-> presentModalViewController -> MFMessageComposeViewController object

So on message compose `didFinishWithResult` delegate I want to go back to A Controller not on B.

I have tried several steps like 2 times dismissModalViewControllerAnimated in delegate and calling A controller directly from delegate but nothing its working. Everytime it dismisses only single time and it remains on B controller.

On cancel/send i want to go back to A controller.

Comment: Since B is modal view controller you need to dismiss the MFMessageComposeViewController, wait for a second before you can dismiss view controller on B.  It will help if you add code on how you dismiss B and MFMessageComposeViewController.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you mentioned, dismiss it twice.
First with, `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Then, `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Great Man.... I was messing with this problem since last 1 hour... tried so many complex ways.... and your answer was so simple and accurate. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: In your B controller set a flag when you present to MFMessageComposeViewController. In your B's view will appear check if the the flag is set then dismiss B and unset the flag.

Method 2: dismiss B just before presenting MFMessageComposeViewController